# How to read hyperlinks of image, and content of header and footer in docx file using php?

Tags: php, hyperlink, header, footer, docx

I have problem with reading hyperlink of image in docx file using php. Also I couldn't read content of header and footer in same docx file. I found PHPDOCX as a close neighbor to work on DOCX file but still I couldn't find this answer.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Navaraj

Answer (score 1):

not sure about docx but it will work for doc ,try below

```
function parseWord($userDoc) 
        {
            $fileHandle = fopen($userDoc, "r");
            $line = @fread($fileHandle, filesize($userDoc));   
            $lines = explode(chr(0x0D),$line);
            $outtext = "";
            foreach($lines as $thisline)
              {
                $pos = strpos($thisline, chr(0x00));
                if (($pos !== FALSE)||(strlen($thisline)==0))
                  {
                  } else {
                    $outtext .= $thisline." ";
                  }
              }
             $outtext = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s\,\.\-\n\r\t@\/\_\(\)]/","",$outtext);
             return $outtext;

        } 
        $text = parseWord("1.doc");
        echo $text;
```

it will identify the hyperlink , then you can use simple logic. headers and footers are also pulled

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joelle, I tested above code and found out that it can identify hyperlink for regular text not inside image, is that so? Previosuly I have used following regular expression for normal hyperlink detection.  

  $str = preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '<a href="\0">\4</a>', $str );  
     
  Any way thank you very much for your help.

Comment: well i have used it for normal text parsing .. you can surely modify regex to make it working for images